# Eclipse 3.4 + Tomcat 6.0 + Remote Debugging with Console Output

Tags: eclipse, debugging, tomcat, console

I'm using this configuration:

Eclipse 3.4 + Tomcat 6.0 + Remote Debugging

It's working great, I can debug a servlet and so on, no problems.

But, my servlet console output is going to $CATALINA_HOME/logs/catalina.out.

Is that possible to redirect to the Eclipse console window?

I use Log4J in my project but every entry goes to catalina.out and not my console window. It's really annoying.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend getting the LogFile Tools plugin for eclipse: http://sourceforge.net/projects/logfiletools/

It gives you a new log file view that you can add word-based highlighting and essentially tail any file (such as the tomcat log). I usually have it highlight errors in red, for example so they pop out when viewing the log.

The other alternative is to actually start tomcat from within eclipse. You can do this via the eclipse web tools (a bit heavy) or the sysdeo tomcat launcher plugin (lightweight but doesn't do much but launch and update contexts)

Hope this helps!